# Reading request data on RESTlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, restlet

I am trying to create a restful service, using GAE and RESTlet on the server side and jQuery on the client side. Dispite the very poor documentation on RESTlet, I am determined to familiarise myself with a restful framework. However, I can't even get the basic functionality out of it.

The problem I have is that out of GET, POST, PUT and DELETE, only DELETE requests appear to deliver the data part.

The calls are made like this:

```
function put() {
    try {
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type : "PUT", //Same for GET, POST and DELETE
            data : data,
            success : function(data) {
                try {
                    $("#results").text(data);
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

On the server-side I have a resource attached on a router, and it goes like this:

```java
public class TaskResource extends ServerResource
{
    String  userID  = "jada";

    @Override
    public void doInit()
    {
        super.doInit();
        userID = (String) getRequestAttributes().get("user");
    }

    @Get
    public String toString(String str)
    {
        return "GET: task of " + userID + "  |||  DATA: " + str;
    }

    @Put
    public String putit(String str)
    {
        return "PUT: task of " + userID + "  |||  DATA: " + str;
    }

    @Post
    public String postit(String str)
    {
        return "POST: task of " + userID + "  |||  DATA: " + str;
    }

    @Delete
    public String deleteit(String str)
    {
        return "DELETE: task of " + userID + "  |||  DATA: " + str;
    }
}
```

In the four cases above, as str, GET gets a null argument (understandable), PUT and POST get empty strings and DELETE gets the data actually sent.

I have experimented with changing the type of the arguments (to Representation or Form) and with more specific annotations (e.g @Get("xml")). No success so far.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: What is the format of your 'data' that you are sending???

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation: Use a better-documented ReST framework. They're definitely out there. [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/getting-started.html), for example, is really easy to get up and running, and it has the benefit of being an implementation of JAX-RS, of which there are several other mature implementations that you can play around with once you learn the API.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are trying to fetch the request entity.  I'm not sure if methods marked with `@Put` or `@Post` should have the request entity automatically passed in like you are expecting.  I'm not sure why it works for `DELETE` though and not the others.  Anyways, try the code below out and see if you get anything.  If `getEntityAsText()` still comes up empty, there is likely something else going on.

Try this out:

```
@Put
public String putit() {
   return this.getRequest().getEntityAsText();
}
```

Comment: getRequest().getEntityAsText() returns null in PUT and POST. DELETE works again. Also, PUT and POST don't work (meaning there's no response to the browser) when declared with no arguments.